# Macro not moving the string after the character found

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to move the cell value to adjacent cell if the string contains @ character in it. but the following  Macro is not working as intended.

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim MatchString As String
  MatchString = "@"
  For Counter = 1 To Range("A:A").Count
    If (InStr(Range("A" & Counter).Value, Len(MatchString)) = MatchString) Then
      Range("A" & Counter).Select
      Selection.Cut
      Range("B" & Counter).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
  Next Counter
End Sub
```

Kindly suggest me what I missed in this macro so that my program works well.

Comment: you are looking for `"(If ISCunable to resolve,"` not `"@"`

Comment: oops need to edit... still not working

Comment: You are also only looking if the left character is `@`, not if the string contains `@`

Comment: what I need to change... is there a flaw?

Comment: Use `Instr()` to check.

Comment: `If "myCell.Value" Like "*@*" Then` can also be helpful. Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator)

Comment: Still nt working ... let me update the code again.

Comment: @Masoud Can you please help me where I need to edit in the code?

Comment: Now you are trying to find `1` in the string with `InStr(Range("A" & Counter).Value, Len(MatchString))` remove the `Len()` as it returns a number of the length of the string. `InStr(MatchString,Range("A" & Counter).Value)`.  please research what each part does and how to use it, we are not wikipedia.

Comment: You know `Range("A:A").Count` will take forever to run? Apply this as well [How to loop through a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000953/excel-vba-loop-through-cells-in-a-column-if-not-empty-print-cell-value-into)

Comment: Have timed the two answers with 160 entries of `@` - FIND method took 47 ms, whole column took 10093ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work; using **[`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator)**

```
Sub Macro1()

  With ActiveSheet
  For Counter = 1 To .Range("A:A").Count
    If .Range("A" & Counter).Value Like "*@*" Then

      .Range("A" & Counter).Cut .Range("B" & Counter)
      Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If
  Next Counter
  End With

End Sub
```

You should avoid selecting/activating in VBA:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

If you don't really want to loop over an entire column read this:

[EXCEL VBA - Loop through cells in a column, if not empty, print cell value into another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000953/excel-vba-loop-through-cells-in-a-column-if-not-empty-print-cell-value-into)

As posted as another answer, `Find` would be a good approach (faster) toward this problem.

Comment: Thank you. it really helped.

Comment: ++ perfect answer. Just to add, after cut/copy its good to add Application.CutCopyMode=False. No harm. :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather then looking at every cell in column A just go straight to the cells with FIND.

Each time @ is found it will be moved to column B and the value in column A is removed.  When there's no more to find the loop will stop.

```
Public Sub MoveToAdjactent()

    Dim MatchString As String
    Dim rFound As Range

    MatchString = "@"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
        Set rFound = .Find(MatchString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            Do
                rFound.Offset(, 1) = rFound
                rFound.ClearContents
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That's how you should do it. Loops are bad practices. +1