# expand vba code to act the same for multiple rows without deleting all information in different rows based on a cell in a different rows value

Tags: excel, vba

i am using this code in excel vba  and it is working fine for this row however i am wanting to apply the code to work in the same way but for all the rows in the m column based on the specific rows value and not clear contents of all the rows in the other columns based on 1 cell in the m columns value, hope this makes sense

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M4")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("N4:T4").ClearContents        
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "based on the specific rows value" mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think you want to [loop through the cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000953/excel-vba-loop-through-cells-in-a-column-if-not-empty-print-cell-value-into) in column `M`

Comment: When cell M4 changes only cells N4 to T4 clears

Comment: and then when m5 changes only cells n5 to t5 clear

Comment: hope this helps i'm new to all this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, using `Offset` and `Resize` on the `Intersect`ion of `Target` and column M.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M:M")) Is Nothing Then
        Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M:M")).Offset(, 1).Resize(, 7).ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
```